# RSpec: Avoid using allow any instance of to receive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubocop, rubocop-rspec

I'm working on one old part of code.

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(SportRateManager)
    .to receive(:create)
    .and_return(true)
end
```

There is Rubocop error like:

> Avoid stubbing using 'allow_any_instance_of'

I read about [RuboCop::RSpec:AnyInstance](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.7.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/AnyInstance) and I tried to change it like bellow.

From this

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(SportRateManager)
    .to receive(:create)
    .and_return(true)
end
```

To this:

```
let(:sport_manager) { instance_double(SportRateManager) }

before do
  allow(SportRateManager).to receive(:new).and_return(sport_manager)
  allow(sport_manager).to receive(:create).and_return(true)
end
```

And with full context:
- before

```
describe 'POST create' do
    let(:sport_rate) { build(:sport_rate) }
    let(:action) { post :create, sport_rate: sport_rate.attributes }

    context 'when sport rate manager created the rate successfully' do
      before do
        allow_any_instance_of(SportRateManager)
          .to receive(:create)
          .and_return(true)
      end

      it 'returns ok status' do
        action
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
      end
    end
```

... - after:

```
describe 'POST create' do
    let(:sport_rate) { build(:sport_rate) }
    let(:action) { post :create, sport_rate: sport_rate.attributes }
    let(:sport_manager) { instance_double(SportRateManager) }

    context 'when sport rate manager created the sport successfully' do
      before do
        allow(SportRateManager).to receive(:new).and_return(sport_manager)
        allow(sport_manager).to receive(:create).and_return(true)
      end

      it 'returns ok status' do
        action
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
      end
    end
```

But this doesn't pass the test with error:

`#<InstanceDouble(SportRateManager) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :sport_rate with (no args)`

Comment: Can you also share the code you're testing? Replacing bad way of mocking with just different mocking is not the best idea, Probably you should change the tested code, but it's hard to tell how without seeing it.

Comment: What about `allow(SportRateManager).to receive(:create).and_return(sport_manager)`? The _instance_ doesn't receive create, the class does.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The solution was almost done. You probably need to add `build :sport_rate` before create

Sth like that

```
let(:sport_manager) { instance_double(SportRateManager) }

before do
  allow(SportRateManager).to receive(:new).and_return(sport_manager)
  allow(sport_manager).to receive(:sport_rate).and_return(build :sport_rate)
  allow(sport_manager).to receive(:create).and_return(true)
end
```